# python package from git override conda package version

Tags: python, git, anaconda, spyder

Sometimes I need to checkout a specific branch of a python package from github.
Branch is checked out and I run the standard `python setup.py install` from the directory of the package.

This installs fine. If I open a jupyter notebook (from anaconda prompt), then the package works as expected. But when I open Spyder (from anaconda navigator), the version of the package is from the anaconda installation.

How do I get my Spyder to recognize the branch in my github folder over the conda version? I think it is to do with python path system environment variables (?), but I never managed to get this set up properly.

N.B. This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Try finding out the interpreter being used on each of your situations `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Install `python setup.py install` using each of the interpreters.

Comment: thanks@SergioPulgarin - did not know this check. However, executables are the same

Comment: That's a bit strange. Take a look (in case you haven't) at this, maybe it's helpful https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder (check step #5)